# Pytorch not accepting GPU devices

Tags: python, pytorch

I am working on DeepLab V3 model from the repo mentioned in the link below.

link: https://github.com/jfzhang95/pytorch-deeplab-xception

When I am trying to run on more than one GPU, I am getting the following error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "train.py", line 313, in <module>
    main()
  File "train.py", line 302, in main
    trainer = Trainer(args)
  File "train.py", line 76, in __init__
    self.model = torch.nn.DataParallel(self.model, device_ids=[1,2,3]).to(args.cuda)
  File "/home/deshpand/anaconda3/envs/torch_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/nn/parallel/data_parallel.py", line 145, in __init__
    _check_balance(self.device_ids)
  File "/home/deshpand/anaconda3/envs/torch_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/nn/parallel/data_parallel.py", line 25, in _check_balance
    dev_props = _get_devices_properties(device_ids)
  File "/home/deshpand/anaconda3/envs/torch_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/_utils.py", line 577, in _get_devices_properties
    return [_get_device_attr(lambda m: m.get_device_properties(i)) for i in device_ids]
  File "/home/deshpand/anaconda3/envs/torch_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/_utils.py", line 577, in <listcomp>
    return [_get_device_attr(lambda m: m.get_device_properties(i)) for i in device_ids]
  File "/home/deshpand/anaconda3/envs/torch_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/_utils.py", line 558, in _get_device_attr
    return get_member(torch.cuda)
  File "/home/deshpand/anaconda3/envs/torch_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/_utils.py", line 577, in <lambda>
    return [_get_device_attr(lambda m: m.get_device_properties(i)) for i in device_ids]
  File "/home/deshpand/anaconda3/envs/torch_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/cuda/__init__.py", line 374, in get_device_properties
    raise AssertionError("Invalid device id")
AssertionError: Invalid device id
```

The line for which i am getting this error is mentioned below.

```
self.model = torch.nn.DataParallel(self.model, device_ids=[1,2,3])
```

I am using `os.environ["CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES"] = "1,2,3"` in the program.Still I am facing this issue.

Can someone please help me with this?

Comment: What does `torch.cuda.device_count()` return?

Comment: it returns the correct count of devices. There are 4 devices. But I want to use only three as one is out of commission. Here is output of above command.

```>>> print(torch.cuda.device_count())
4
```

Comment: This seems improbable given your result of `torch.cuda.device_count`, but just a sanity check, you're not running a cpu-only version of pytorch right? `torch.__version__`

Comment: I am 100% sure that I am NOT using cpu-only version. Because, other deep learning models work just fine. Problem is only with this one program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At least on my system (Ubuntu 20.04 running torch `1.12.1+cu102`) it seems that `torch.cuda` indexes devices starting from zero based on available devices during initialization, and not on the system device id. So when you hide the first GPU with `os.environ` and import torch, it thinks that the second, third and fourth devices are actually `cuda:0`, `cuda:1` and `cuda:2`, hence throwing an error when you try to access `cuda:3`.

Comment: So, if I just use 1 and 2, it should work?

Comment: So if your machine has GPUs `[0, 1, 2, 3]` and you only want to use `[1, 2, 3]`, everything should work as expected by simply not touching `CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES`. If you need to ensure torch won't be able to access the first device at all, set the environment variable as you do and pass `device_ids=[0, 1, 2]` to `DataParallel`.

Comment: This sort of worked. I am able to go ahead in the program. I made all devices visible when using ```os.environ["CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES"]```.  But, now I am getting this error.

``` 
RuntimeError: module must have its parameters and buffers on device cuda:1 (device_ids[0]) but found one of them on device: cuda:0
```

Comment: @programmer_04_03 My bad, I was incorrect in the previous comment. Checking the documentation for `DataParallel` reveals that *the parallelized module must have its parameters and buffers on device_ids[0]*. Try setting the visible devices as in the original question and use `device_ids=[0,1,2]` instead.

Comment: It worked after doing this so I will mark this answer as correct. But, what if someone wants to use only GPUs 1 and 2. Won't the DataParallel create a problem in that case?

Comment: @programmer_04_03 Can't say for sure as I haven't worked with DDP with only a part of the GPUs available, but I'm guessing initially copying the module to the device specified at `device_ids[0]` would do the trick. I.e., `model.to(torch.device("cuda:1"))` and then `device_ids=[1, 2]`.

Comment: Thanks for the help @simeonovich I will try this with my model.